# how to find the last message from conversation using group by

Tags: php, arrays, message

[image]

I was expecting it was easy but stuck to the problem to find the list of the conversation using group by sender receiver array, Here above is **snapshot** of the database

I have followed the above sequence using group by sender id and receiver id but stuck in getting the conversation which is unique

---

here is the query

```
SELECT tbl_registration.name as sender_name,group_concat(message SEPARATOR '|') as message_list,`sender_reciever_array`,`datetime`,`reciever_id`,`sender_id` FROM `tbl_chatting_view` 
inner join 
tbl_registration
on tbl_registration.id=tbl_chatting_view.sender_id
group by `sender_reciever_array`
```

which produces the following results in php array

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sender_name"]=>
    string(7) "harshit"
    ["message_list"]=>
    string(4) "k|my"
    ["sender_reciever_array"]=>
    string(4) "2,29"
    ["datetime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-06 13:34:09"
    ["reciever_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["sender_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sender_name"]=>
    string(7) "harshit"
    ["message_list"]=>
    string(5) "mohan"
    ["sender_reciever_array"]=>
    string(3) "2,5"
    ["datetime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-08 12:18:45"
    ["reciever_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["sender_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sender_name"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["message_list"]=>
    string(9) "jkgh|test"
    ["sender_reciever_array"]=>
    string(4) "29,5"
    ["datetime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-02 11:31:45"
    ["reciever_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["sender_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sender_name"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["message_list"]=>
    string(56) "Jhadjksdhjkahsjkhdfjshfjhdsjfh|Asdasfdfs|Hgasdhjgdhgsahj"
    ["sender_reciever_array"]=>
    string(5) "29,63"
    ["datetime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-12 12:47:53"
    ["reciever_id"]=>
    string(2) "63"
    ["sender_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    ["sender_name"]=>
    string(10) "Kiran sahu"
    ["message_list"]=>
    string(156) "Asdafdggfhgfj|HhjjhhjjhhFghxfzcgc

Bnasbdjnbfjdjfh


Ninja admonishments

Njkdnsfjkndgnkdfn

|Ghjgsdfhjgfh|Sadas|Dgfjdjkjkhsjkjkas
Dsjmjkdsljflkjsdlkfcjklsd"
    ["sender_reciever_array"]=>
    string(5) "63,29"
    ["datetime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-08-13 05:39:56"
    ["reciever_id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["sender_id"]=>
    string(2) "63"
  }
}
```

Here in the above array there is the last message will come in the message array with the list with the seperator as '|', and in the sender and reciever array there contains in the `two array 63,29 and 29,63` but I need the combination of the two message

Comment: Sorry I can not understand what result you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could mess around with this. Normalize your `GROUP BY` to contain both sides of the conversation? I'm no SQL expert, so downvote away. (receiver is spelled wrong) :D

```
SELECT IF(tcv.sender_id > tcv.reciever_id,
           concat_ws(',', tcv.reciever_id, tcv.sender_id),
           concat_ws(',', tcv.sender_id, .tcvreciever_id)
       ) as both
FROM tbl_chatting_view tcv
GROUP BY both
```